# PHP : Only view the PDF file not downloadable

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to view the PDF document in the browser but not downloadable. I tried some PDF viewer to view but its also have downloading option.

If any user try to download or open PDF from their end, it should have some ***authentication (password protection)***.

And also i tried to open the protected PDF in the browser through **PHP CURL**. But it ask password to open the file.

**How to open the protected PDF in the browser by passing password?**

Here i passed the password for the PDF file..

```
<?php
$username = "";
$password = "demo";
$url = "www.example.com/file.pdf";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header('Content-type:application/pdf');
echo $output;
?>
```

***Here "file.pdf" is protected file.***

Can anyone suggest how to prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

It is totally depend on the PDF viewer option.

Nowadays a lot of modern browser support view and download. I personally do not think this is possible.

What you can do is set the password for people who want to view it. Even they downloaded they don't have the password it also useless for them.